# Actions must have a type property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

My effect appears to be throwing a `Actions must have a type property` it seems to be my `RegisterSuccess` action that is causing the issue, but looking around on SO it could be the way in which I am calling it, I have attempted some of their solutions but they don't seem to work in my case.

**Effect:**

```
 @Effect()
    register = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(AuthActionTypes.REGISTER),
        switchMap(action => this.auth.register(action.registration).pipe(
            map(result => ([
                { type: AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_SUCCESS, user: result }
            ])),
            catchError(result => ([
                { type: AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_FAIL }
            ])),
        ))
    );
```

**Action:**

```
export class Register implements Action {
    readonly type = AuthActionTypes.REGISTER;
    constructor(public registration: Registration) {}
}

export class RegisterSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public user: User) {}
}

export class RegisterFail implements Action {
    readonly type = AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_FAIL;
    constructor() {}
}
```

**Service:**

```
register(user: Registration): Observable<any> {
        return this.api.post('auth/register', user).pipe(map(res => res.data));
    }
```

Comment: Try removing the square brackets (`[]`) you have around the actions you're trying to dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

Your effects are written for NgRx version 8.3.0
Your Action are written for NgRx version 7.4.0

"switchMap(action => this.auth.register(action.registration).pipe(" 
you don't need a pipe here

for NgRx version 8.3.0 it should be something like that:
Action:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
export const register = createAction(AuthActionTypes.REGISTER());
export const registerSuccess = createAction(AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_SUCCESS, props<{user: User}>());
export const registerFail = createAction(AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_FAIL);
```

Effects:

```
@Effect()
    register = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(register.type),
        mergeMap(action => this.auth.register(action.registration),
        map(result => ({ type: registerSuccess.type, user: result })),
        catchError(result => ({ type: registerFail.type })),
        ))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a way to return an action in NGRX

Instead you should return like this

First import your action (Please change your code accordingly)

```
import * as authActions from "user-auth.actions";
```

Then change your effect

```
map(result => {
   return new authActions.RegisterSuccess(result) 
  }
),
catchError(result => ([
   of(authActions.RegisterFail)
])),
```

The line authActions.RegisterSuccess is calling to your class definition

Comment: Thanks, although this a way of triggering multiple actions from one effect. I know that this syntax works as the catch of the LOGIN action works.